# traefik doesn't detect my container with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, traefik

I'm using traefik :

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.9
    # command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    command: --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    command:
      # We are going to use the docker provider
      - --api.insecure=true
      - "--providers.docker"
      # Only enabled containers should be exposed
      #- "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      # We want to use the dashbaord
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      # The entrypoints we ant to expose
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"

        #- "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
        #  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
        #  - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"

      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=$EMAIL"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=acme.json"
      # used during the challenge
```

And separately another docker-compose.yml with database, mailserver, nginx+php-fpm:

```
version: "3"
services:
  database:
    build:
      context: ./database
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '${MYSQL_DATABASE}'
      MYSQL_USER: '${MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}'
    volumes:
      - ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
  php-http:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-nginx/Dockerfile
      args:
        DOMAIN: '${DOMAIN}'
    depends_on:
      - database
      - mailserver
    volumes:
      - ./nginxlogs/:/var/log/nginx/
      - './symfonylogs:/var/www/html/mystuff/var/log/'
        #labels:
            #      - traefik.http.routers.php-http.tls=true
            #      - traefik.http.routers.php-http.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
            #    - traefik.http.services.php-http.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
            #      - traefik.enable=true
            #      - traefik.http.routers.php-http.rule=Host(`mystuff.com`, `mystuff2.com`)
            #   - 'traefik.http.routers.php-http.tls.domains[0].main=mystuff.com'
            #    - 'traefik.http.routers.php-http.tls.domains[1].main=mystuff2.com'

    restart: always

  mailserver:
    [stuffs]
```

The dockerfile for nginx/php-fpm is based on https://github.com/TrafeX/docker-php-nginx/tree/1.10.0.

But I made a few changes in the config.

The nginx.conf :

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log stderr warn;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Define custom log format to include reponse times
    log_format main_timed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                          '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log /dev/stdout main_timed;
    error_log /dev/stderr notice;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # Write temporary files to /tmp so they can be created as a non-privileged user
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    # Default server definition
    server {
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/lib/nginx/html;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to PHP-FPM listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            expires 5d;
        }

        # Deny access to . files, for security
        location ~ /\. {
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }

        # Allow fpm ping and status from localhost
        location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
    #        deny all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # Include other server configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

my website config :

```
server {
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name mystuff.com mystuff2.com;
    root /var/www/html/mystuff/public;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
    # location /bundles {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    # }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        # fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        # fastcgi_param APP_SECRET <app-secret-id>;
        # fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://db_user:db_pass@host:3306/db_name";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        # Caveat: When PHP-FPM is hosted on a different machine from nginx
        #         $realpath_root may not resolve as you expect! In this case try using
        #         $document_root instead.
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
        access_log off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

www.conf:

```
[global]
; Log to stderr
error_log = /dev/stderr

[www]
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nobody
listen.group = nobody
listen.mode = 0660
user = nobody
group = nobody

; Enable status page
pm.status_path = /fpm-status

; Ondemand process manager
pm = ondemand

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 100

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 1000

; Make sure the FPM workers can reach the environment variables for configuration
clear_env = no

; Catch output from PHP
catch_workers_output = yes

; Remove the 'child 10 said into stderr' prefix in the log and only show the actual message
decorate_workers_output = no

; Enable ping page to use in healthcheck
ping.path = /fpm-ping
```

Among other things, I made it listen to /var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock instead of the localhost.

Result : if I try to reach my website, I get a "404 page not found". Without traefik it seems to work (in http).
On the dashboard of traefik, I can see that traefik detect the containers of my database and mailserver, but not php-nginx. It's not in the list.

Update :

```
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:56,736 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:56,739 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:57,742 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:57,744 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 8
php-http_1    | nginx: [emerg] a duplicate default server for [::]:8080 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/symfony-nginx.conf:2
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:57,754 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:57,755 INFO gave up: nginx entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
php-http_1    | [22-Jan-2023 16:27:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql (Error loading shared library /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql.so (Error relocating /usr/lib/php7/modules/pdo_mysql.so: pdo_throw_exception: symbol not found)) in Unknown on line 0
php-http_1    | [22-Jan-2023 16:27:57] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8
php-http_1    | [22-Jan-2023 16:27:57] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
php-http_1    | 2023-01-22 16:27:58,792 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

docker ps:

```
713bd86c922d   docker_php-http     "/usr/bin/supervisor…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes (unhealthy)   8080/tcp                                                                 docker_php-http_1
f80676dda336   docker_database     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes               3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                                                      docker_database_1
a4a50d91722d   docker_mailserver   "/usr/bin/entrypoint…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes (healthy)     25/tcp, 110/tcp, 143/tcp, 465/tcp, 587/tcp, 993/tcp, 995/tcp, 4190/tcp   mailserver
```

I tried billions of small changes, nothing works. I'm getting quite desperate. I had made another build with apache instead of nginx, it works perfectly. I have no idea what's going on. Does anyone has any idea?

Thank you

Update : okay we can see in the docker ps that it's noted as unhealthy. I assume it's related.
In the original docker image, there is this :

```
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=10s CMD curl --silent --fail http://127.0.0.1:8080/fpm-ping
```

I assume it's not correct anymore after my changes.

Comment: Does the container even start properly? By exposing the Docker socket to Traefik, you should make all your containers visible to it (however, visible still doesn't mean it will connect to it, but you should see it in the dashboard). Also, network host and no network for the other containers is discouraged in this setup, create a proper network and make sure to assign all containers to it.

Comment: I updated the post with the start logs, and the docker ps. Do you think it might be undetected because the HEALTHCHECK line isn't correct (bad url), or it's independant? Yeah I'm aware for the network. I'm gonna change it after that issue is fixed